# IF and conditional SUM in Google Doc Spreadsheet

Tags: spreadsheet, google-docs

I am trying to run an IF statement in Google Spreadsheet that will, if "Yes" SUM a series of values.

=IF(G3="Yes",=SUM(C3*D3)+(E3*D3))

This works (if I ignore the IF) and just do =SUM(C3*D3)+(E3*D3), so I know my math is correct.

I have read a few different posts that are asking similar questions, but many have "guesses" and are offering different structured formulas, so I'm not really even sure what the proper structure is any more.

Basically, for the nerdy portion of you, the spreadsheet does the following:

If the "killed" column is Yes, I need to calculate the XP of the monsters killed.

Base XP (C3) times Qty (D3), plus Bonus XP (E3) times Qty (D3) and them SUM the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equal sign (`=`) in front of `SUM` should not be there. If your formula works I guess Google Docs just ignores it. Also, the function `SUM()` is useful to add the values from a range of cells from the same row or column when you don't know in advance how many cells you will add (or there are more than 2 cells and you use `SUM()` because it's less to write).

If I understood your request, the formula you need is:
    =IF(G3="Yes",C3*D3+E3*D3)

Comment: Ug, dead on, thank you!!  I will mark this approved as soon as it will let me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Right now the SUM function is only wrapping C3*D3 then you are adding (E3*D3). This is the same as (C3*D3)+(E3*D3) not using the SUM function. Order of operations tells us there is no need for the parentheses so you could write C3*D3+E3*D3.

The IF function has the following parameters:

```
IF(EVALUATION,IF TRUE,IF FALSE)
```

So your final equation would be:

```
=IF(G3="YES",C3*D3+E3*D3,"")
```

I always add the FALSE return to be blank so that if I need to change it later I can do so.

Comment: Good idea, I noticed after I fixed it it printed "FALSE", so I added the "" to clear it.  Good suggestion.